# how i can insert an image in web browser control in c# with out open image ui?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, html-editor

I have a web browser control in C# that it's design mode is on. I use it to make a (WYSIWYG) HTML editor. I want to insert a photo on this without UI, when user wants to insert image I show to him/her a window that shows on it some known name for user. Then with search (s)he find her/his photo and add it to control.

this is my open image form:

[image: Open Image Form]

Photos are in database and user only know them with names. I upload all of them in a folder and show above list to user and user selects a picture. I want to add image by it's location in hard disk and allow user to set its alignment .

How I can do this ?

Comment: image stored in hard disk?

Comment: Yes, image are in database and i store theme in Hard disk.

Comment: so you want user add image to browser and set alignment for it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a new element to a document is very logical. The first step is to create the node (element) you wish to append, the next is to find where you wish to append it within the document, and the final step is to actually do the appending.

I write an Example for you:

```
  private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body></img></body></html>";
    }

    private void insert_image_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElement userimage = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("img");
        userimage.SetAttribute("src", "image location");
        userimage.Id = "imageid";
        webBrowser1.Document.Body.AppendChild(userimage);
    }
    private void btn_set_aliign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("imageid").SetAttribute("float", "right");
    }
```

Comment: @Yekta Mghani: working with web-browser is pretty easy,have fun +1 from me